# Linux socket recv return -1,errno 110 connection timed out

Tags: c++, c

Connection correctly established，Appear after a period of time.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?!

Comment: (well, it doesn't need to be *verifiable* by us but minimal code with which *you* can reproduce it)

Comment: This is one of those times where a MCVE would not help.   It's a network issue, and the OP's network cannot be posted in an SO question:)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a networked system problem on a network that is not included in the question:)

Comment: @MartinJames it could, because a recv can timeout for various reasons... now we don't even know if OP whether OP is using IPX or Unix sockets...

Answer (score 4):

The [manual page of recv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/recv.3p.html) states for error `ETIMEDOUT`:

> The connection timed out during connection establishment, or due to a transmission timeout on active connection.

The reason for this error can be manyfold depending in the type of socket you are using.

If we assume that you are using a TCP socket:

```
int tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

It could mean that your communication partner did not send an acknowledge in time.

Comment: For Linux better use the reference pages here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html or here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/recv.3p.html

Answer (score 1):

If you got this on `connect()`, it means the remote host didn't respond to the connection request, either because of a firewall or a network connectivity problem such as a pulled cable.

If you got this on an established TCP connection, it means the remote host didn't acknowledge TCP segments sent from your host within your host's timeout period, which indicates either a dead host, dead connection, or cable pull.

Comment: clearly from `recv`, which is why you should ask for a [mcve] ;)

Comment: How about the *question title?*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If *you* need more detail, feel free to ask for it, but don't put it on to me. I don't need it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm confused  when server call close(sock) , client call recv() but recv nothing.Under normal circumstances，recv must return zero and means server close  this connection but client recv just like died. it's means in a very poor network environment when close socket desthost maybe lost (fin+ack) package?